# Can a late passport renewal affect getting visas?

Tags: visas, passports, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan. If I renew my Passport months after it expires, can that hurt my chance of getting a Visa later?

For example, a passport expires in AUG 2020 and I renew it in MARCH 2021.

Comment: one data point. I let my Canadian passport expire while I was too ill to travel and only renewed it many months later. I applied for a Chinese visa and got far more than I asked for (I asked for one visit; I got multi visit for the almost-ten-years that remained on the passport.) I am not even sure how other countries would know the history of your previous passports and when you renewed.

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question correctly, and you wonder about any impact on future visa applications (i.e. **after** you have your new passport, say in April 2021 in your example), I doubt this would have any effect.

Countries you haven't yet visited/applied a visa for generally won't even know about it.

And even if they have the information, I don't see how this would matter for any country.

Answer (score 3):

No. As a matter of fact, people that rarely travel don't care about renewing their passport until they need to travel.

What I mean to say is that not everyone is a frequent traveler, and I know for sure a number of people who just had no interest in traveling for decades, so why spending money for renewing a travel document they won't use?

A passport has a limited life. A passport expires and a new one is issued. We usually call it *renewal*, but it's actually an issue of a brand new document every time.

A visa is released to the individual by judging the individual and the personal history (e.g. past refusals and criminal records). No country we know about cares about the status of frequent flyer and the periods spent in the home country without traveling

Comment: Just to modulate this a bit: having a travel history, especially in "rich" countries when you come from a "less rich" one, is a positive sign, it shows you came to the country and left when you were supposed to. It also shows one has means to travel. It gives confidence to the visa or immigration officer that you can be trusted, as opposed to someone who never left their own country and suddenly asks for a visa while having little or no ties to their home country. But it definitely shouldn't matter if the applicant is not travelling all the time ever year. Especially in Covid times!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the country you want to obtain a visa from, and the type of visa. Some countries will issue visas that are valid only until the passport expires, others accept visas in expired passports if you have both the old and new passport with you.

If you want to apply for a visa in the period between expiration of the old and issue of the new passport, you're probably out of luck.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question (or I did). I believe OP wonders if a "whole" between passport validities can affect **later** visa applications.

Comment: The original question didn't specify when the visa application is intended, I think I did misunderstand it. Your interpretation makes more sense.